# Deploy to emulator in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, deployment, android-emulator, xamarin

I have been using Xamarin to develop some Android applications. I am now using Xamarin with Visual Studio and I have a question.

My question is this... How do I deploy my app to the emulator? I have started the emulator, but am not sure how to do this in Visual Studio.

May I please have some help?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have followed the steps on the page and the steps do not work.

If I do this:
Debug->Start Debugging, the following message appears:

```
Device: [A]-AndroidAPILevel17NonGoogle is either not running or not attached.

Please attach an Android device, or select an emulator from the dropdown list to launch it.

NOTE : Launching Android emulators can take a few minutes. Please be patient or use a real Android device, they are much quicker!
```

I can start the emulator by doing the following:
Tools->Open Android Emulator Manager
and then selecting the emulator.

However, once the emulator has started up, I am not sure how to deploy the application to the emulator.

If I select:
Debug->Start Debugging... nothing happens

May I have some help please?

Comment: by emulator, do you mean the real device? because simply starting a debug should run on an emulator preselected or your selected one. if not, can you please some screen captures. I would suggest you to use xamarin android emulator, it is much faster and requires less ram than VS emulators. it requires some setup though as described xamarins page. I personally prefer to use a real device debugging, it is without any hassle and much faster. you can also see how your app looks like on a device as emulator might not be same as device.

Comment: Is it resolved for you .?